# what's wrong in this PDO script

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

Here i am writing a script which will send three different values to a database using a simple html form.But whenever i submit the form no values are inserted and i get the following error :

[image: error]

what might be the reason for this error.How can i fix this problem.

```
$server='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$dbname='fruits';
if(isset($_POST['name']) &&isset($_POST['colour']) && isset($_POST['calories'])){
   if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['colour']) && !empty($_POST['calories'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
$colour=$_POST['colour'];
$calories=$_POST['calories'];
try{
$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=$server,dbname=$dbname,$user,$password');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO favfruit(name,colour,calories) 
                      VALUES(:name,:colour,:calories)");

$stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$name,':colour'=>$colour,':calories'=>$calories));
echo 'it was successfully entered to database';
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'error : '.$e->getMessage();
}
}
}
```

HTML form :

```
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>
    fruit name :<input type='text' placeholder='fruit name' name='name'></br>
    colur      :<input type='text' placeholder='fruit colour' name='colour'></br>
    calories   :<input type='text' placeholder='calories' name='calories'></br>
    <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT FORM'>
</form>
```

Comment: is XAMPP turned on? Also, check to see XAMPP is not running on something like localhost:8081 instead of just localhost.

Comment: i checked using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and it returned 'localhost'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is just a typo. Replace

```
$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=$server,dbname=$dbname,$user,$password');
```

by

```
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname",$user,$password);
```

Comment: single quote didn't work but double quote did the trick.Don't know why but it worked finally

Comment: Sorry for that. I missed this. Variables inside strings are replaced only in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings.php');
class db extends pdo{
    //variables
    public $db = '';
    public $config;
    public $settings = array(
        'host'      => SERVER,
        'database'  => DB,
        'username'  => USER,
        'password'  => PASS,
    );

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->settings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->settings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->settings['username']}",
            "{$this->settings['password']}"
        );

        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Within the settings.php file define the constants for your db connection
then create a new function.

```
 public function InsertFruit() {
 if(isset($_POST['name']) &&isset($_POST['colour']) && isset($_POST['calories'])){
       if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['colour']) && !empty($_POST['calories'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $colour=$_POST['colour'];
    $calories=$_POST['calories'];
    try{
    $query = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO favfruit(name,colour,calories)
    VALUES(:name,:colour,:calories)
SQL;
    $resource = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $resource->execute(array(
    'name'  => $_POST['name'],
    'colour' => $_POST['colour'],
    'calories' => $_POST['calories'],
));
    echo $_POST['name'].' entered into database';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO favfruit(name,colour,calories) 
                          VALUES(:name,:colour,:calories)");

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'error : '.$e->getMessage();
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

I know for sure as long as your webserver is up and running that this will work for your connection and that it will ease any other connections you need to use later on. As for your actual form just use a case process to determine what function is ran.